# How to update 1 row only in SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table ,for example, `members` and these is its data

```
Id            first_name        gender
1             Alexis            Female
2             Luke              Male
3             Jireh             Male
4             Luke              Male
```

How do I update the first `Luke` in the table?

Doing `UPDATE members SET first_name='Eduard' WHERE first_name='Luke'` changes both Luke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `UPDATE` on the Id column rather than on `FirstName` in the `WHERE` clause. As shown below.

```
UPDATE members
SET first_name = 'Eduard'
WHERE Id = 2
```

The benefits of doing it by ID is that you know the exact row you are updating rather than assuming the `member` you are attempting to update is the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) members 
SET first_name='Eduard' 
WHERE first_name='Luke'
```

OR

you can use `ROWCOUNT`

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

UPDATE members 
SET first_name='Eduard' 
WHERE first_name='Luke'

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: This works in MS-SQL but the question was about sqllite - neither are valid.   It seems LIMIT can be used sometimes but not always . See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345789/sqlite-how-to-use-update-and-limit-at-the-same-time