# SQLite how to use UPDATE and LIMIT at the same time?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, sql-delete, sql-limit

What I'm looking for is to update only 1 row in a table where all the entries are, in the beginning, zero.
After a while surfing the internet for answers, I found out that `LIMIT` should work fine with `UPDATE`, but also not quite. From what I've seen, I should have "enabled" some stuff with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`, but I have no idea what that is or where and when I should have done it.
I've also seen different solutions for those in my situation, things like:

```
UPDATE Table_name
Set Column_name= new_value
WHERE Column_name IN 
(   SELECT Column_name
    FROM Table_name
    WHERE Column_name = initial_value
    LIMIT 1
)
```

But this, for some reason, is not working for me. The `LIMIT 1` has absolutely no effect, as the entire column gets modified.

Is it because I'm using the same column name in both `SET/SELECT` and in `WHERE`?

My table only consists of a single column.

Comment: You have to first build a custom version of sqlite3.c with limit enabled for update, and then compile it with that `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` defined. It's easy if you're comfortable with C and building stuff from source. If you're using some other language? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the minimum (or maximum) [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) of the rows that satisfy your conditions and use it to update only 1 row:

```
UPDATE Table_name
Set Column_name= new_value
WHERE rowid = (   
  SELECT MIN(rowid)
  FROM Table_name
  WHERE Column_name = initial_value
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: for your question to make sense at all, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows, so you can consistently tell which record should be updated. That would typically be the primary key of your table. Let me assume that this column is called `id`.

Then, you could write your query as:

```
update table_name
set column_name = 'new value'
where column_name = 'initial value'
order by id
limit 1
```

*If* you don't have a primary key column, it is technically possible to remove the `order by` clause. One arbitrary row will be updated.

```
update table_name
set column_name = 'new value'
where column_name = 'initial value'
limit 1
```

Note that, for this to work, you need to have SQLite compiled with option `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` enabled (which is not that easy to do, as commented by Shawn and forpas).

If you don't have that option but you have a primary key column, then you could filter with a subquery:

```
update table_name
set column_name = 'new value'
where id = (
    select min(t1.id) 
    from table_name t1 
    where t1.column_name = 'initial value'
)
```

Comment: SQLite does not support order by or limit in the update statement: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: @forpas: unless it was compiled with option `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`...

Comment: Read Shawn's comment under the question and https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html All this applies to custom versions of SQLite.

Comment: @forpas: understood. I updated my answer with more details and an alternative solution (which requires a primary key though).